# Powershell Add-Content doesn't add to end of file

Tags: powershell

I need to add a header to a csv file before importing it to a database. For some reason the header is added but the rest of the csv data isn't added on a newline but directly after it.

```
$file = Get-ChildItem \\some path to the datafile\IDM_dump | sort LastWriteTime | select -last 1
Copy-Item $file.FullName "D:\Program Files (x86)\Indocs\DatabaseImport\IDMdump.csv"

#Make copy of header info file because file will be renamed
Copy-Item 'D:\Program Files (x86)\Indocs\DatabaseImport\IDMheaderinfo.csv' 'D:\Program Files (x86)\Indocs\DatabaseImport\headerinfo.csv'

#Add header data at the first line of the data file
$valueDumpFile = Get-Content "D:\Program Files (x86)\Indocs\DatabaseImport\IDMdump.csv"

#Add-Content -Path 'D:\Program Files (x86)\Indocs\DatabaseImport\headerinfo.csv' -Value $valueDumpFile
Out-File -FilePath 'D:\Program Files (x86)\Indocs\DatabaseImport\headerinfo.csv' -InputObject $valueDumpFile -Append -NoClobber

#Rename file to new name
Rename-Item -Path 'D:\Program Files (x86)\Indocs\DatabaseImport\headerinfo.csv' -NewName IDMDumpWithHeader.csv
```

Comment: I have tried both Add-Content and Out-file. When using Add-Content the first line of the SvalueDumpfile is added after the first headerline. When using Out-File the all data is added after the first headerline and between every character there is a space added.

Comment: Thanks for cleaning up my code and for the new information on this. Didn't know this way was possible. I'll try it out and give feedback.

Answer (score 1):

As you're not using the data within Powershell, I would just treat the csv files as plain text and use `Get-Content` to join the files:

```
Get-Content $file1,$file2 | Set-Content $output_file
```

The order your specify the files is the order they are joined.

You don't need any copies of files or renaming, just join the files and output once to the desired name file:

```
$headers = 'D:\Program Files (x86)\Indocs\DatabaseImport\IDMheaderinfo.csv'
$output = 'D:\Program Files (x86)\Indocs\DatabaseImport\IDMDumpWithHeader.csv'

$file = Get-ChildItem \\server\IDM_dump | sort LastWriteTime | select -last 1

Get-Content $headers,$file.fullname | Set-Content $output
```

Comment: Glad I could help, if you're happy with my answer you can [Mark it as Accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Answer (score 1):

If you still want to use `Get-Content`, check [@James C.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2208505/james-c)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51651050/9902555). In this answer I suggest different approach which **might be more useful if you need to modify the data in the script, not only to join the files**.

---

Wouldn't it be easier to use CSV-related cmdlets for it?

```
$object = Import-CSV .\data.csv -Header ((Get-Content .\headers.csv) -split ",")
```

Assuming the content of your files is as follows:

#### headers.csv

```
firstname,lastname,id
```

#### data.csv

```
john,doe,2
john,smith,1
```

The result will be the object:

```
PS C:\SO\51650194> $object = Import-CSV .\data.csv -Header ((Get-Content .\headers.csv) -split ",")
PS C:\SO\51650194> $object

firstname lastname id
--------- -------- --
john      doe      2
john      smith    1
```

You can then easily export it to `.csv` using `Export-CSV`.

Comment: This is surely a long time approach. I'll look at this also

Comment: @EricFeurich This one is probaly better if the files are expanding over time and you want to keep a clear overview! :)
Also don't forget to [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) the answer that you found most helpful.